# ¿Cómo almacenar texto/imagen en una bd sqlite local y mostrarlos en un maestro-detalle?

Tags: android-sqlite

Soy nuevo en android y tengo una duda:
¿Qué clase debería modificar para que se conecte a la bd `sqlite` local y traiga el texto y las imágenes? No he encontrado ningún ejemplo de maestro-detalle trayendo datos de una bd y mostrarlos.
Si me pudieran mostrar un ejemplo por favor, gracias. No agrego los xml sino el post quedaría muy largo, pero la siguiente imagen muestra la estructura del proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
public class Persona {
private int id;
private String nombre="";
private String apellido="";
private String telefono="";
private String correo="";
public Persona(){}

public Persona(int i,String n,String a, String t,String c){
    this.id=i;
    this.nombre=n;
    this.apellido=a;
    this.telefono=t;
    this.correo=c;
}
public int getId(){return id;}
public void setId(int i){this.id=i;}
public String  getNombre(){return nombre;}
public void  setNombre(String n){this.nombre=n;}
public String  getApellido(){return apellido;}
public void  setApellido(String a){this.apellido=a;}
public String  getTelefono(){return telefono;}
public void  setTelefono(String t){this.telefono=t;}
public String  getCorreo(){return correo;}
public void  setCorreo(String c){this.correo=c;}
@Override
public String toString(){
    return nombre+" "+apellido;
}}








import java.util.ArrayList;
public class PersonaContent {
private static ArrayList<Persona> personList=new ArrayList();
public static ArrayList getPersonList(){
    return personList;
}
public static void loadPersonList(){
    Persona person;
    person=new Persona();
    person.setId(1);
    person.setNombre("Alvaro");
    person.setApellido("Gelpud");
    person.setTelefono("123");
    person.setCorreo("alvaro@gmail.com");
    personList.add(person);
    person=new Persona();
    person.setId(1);
    person.setNombre("Steven");
    person.setApellido("Hurtado");
    person.setTelefono("123");
    person.setCorreo("steven@gmail.com");
    personList.add(person);
    person=new Persona();
    person.setId(1);
    person.setNombre("Juan");
    person.setApellido("Bastidas");
    person.setTelefono("123");
    person.setCorreo("juan@gmail.com");
    personList.add(person);
}}




public class PersonaListActivity extends AppCompatActivity
implements PersonaListFragment.Callbacks {
private boolean mTwoPane;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_persona_app_bar);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle(getTitle());
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton)                  findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
    if (findViewById(R.id.persona_detail_container) != null) {
        mTwoPane = true;
        ((PersonaListFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.persona_list))
                .setActivateOnItemClick(true);
    }
}
@Override
public void onItemSelected(String id) {
    if (mTwoPane) {
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putString(PersonaDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, id);
        PersonaDetailFragment fragment = new PersonaDetailFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(arguments);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.persona_detail_container, fragment).commit();
    } else {
        Intent detailIntent = new Intent(this, PersonaDetailActivity.class);
        detailIntent.putExtra(PersonaDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, id);
        startActivity(detailIntent);
    }
}}


public class PersonaDetailFragment extends Fragment {
public static final String ARG_ITEM_ID = "item_id";
public PersonaDetailFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments().containsKey(ARG_ITEM_ID)) {
        int index = Integer.valueOf(getArguments().getString(ARG_ITEM_ID));
        person=(Persona) PersonaContent.getPersonList().get(index);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_persona_detail, container, false);
    if(person!=null){
       ((TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textViewNombre)).setText(person.getNombre());
       ((TextView)       rootView.findViewById(R.id.textViewApellido)).setText(person.getApellido());
        ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTelefono)).setText(person.getTelefono());
        ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCorreo)).setText(person.getCorreo());
    }
    return rootView;
}
```

}

Comment: Primero que nada seria mejor que desde tu base de datos guardaras únicamente la ruta hacia las imágenes. Y la ruta puedes colocarla en la tarjeta SD. De esta forma agilizas el proceso de carga de las imágenes y no lo almacenas en la base de datos lo cual la volvería más pesada. Si lo que deseas es mostrar imágenes propias de tu aplicación deberías únicamente guardarlas en drawable y hacer referencia a ellas desde la aplicación.. Para lo del texto te dejo el siguiente link:
[Link tutorial SQlite](http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2014/10/android-sqlite-bases-de-datos/) Espero haberte ayudado.